# Has anyone experienced this border formatting in HTML Table and found a solution?

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, html-table

I have a Google Script Written to do a mail merge which has an embedded table In the email there is a 1px gap between my border in my html formatted table.

I am using the understood table='border-collapse: collapse;Border:1px solid black;. Has anyone ever seen this error or know a solution?

```
var TABLEFORMAT = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><style>table {border- 
  collapse:collapse} table,td,th{border:1px solid black}</style>'  

    for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++)
          { 
            for (col = 1 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
              if (row == 0 && col == 1) {htmltable += '<tr><th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#D5D8DC">' + data[row][col] + '</th>';}
               else
        if (row == 0 && col == lastCol - 1) {htmltable += '<th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#D5D8DC">' + data[row][col] + '</th></tr>';}       else
                if (row == 0) {htmltable += '<th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#D5D8DC">' + data[row][col] + '</th>';}
              else
                if (data[row][0] == employeeId && col == 1) {htmltable += '<tr><td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;">' + data[row][col] +  '</td>';}
              else
                if (data[row][0] == employeeId && col == lastCol) {htmltable += '<tr><td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;">' + data[row][col] + '</td></tr>';}
              else
              if (data[row][0] == employeeId) {htmltable += '<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;">' + data[row][col] + "</td>";}
    }
```

Has anyone ever seen this error or know a solution?

[image]

Comment: Where is `<table>` tag?

Comment: @TheMaster is right. You've declared styles for the `<table>` tag, but it doesn't look like you've included the tag itself. `border-collapse: collapse;` will only apply to the `<table>` element so if it's missing it won't get applied. Not forgetting that it will also be invalid code